# Strict warning: Only variables should be passed by reference

Tags: 7

I get the following error:

> Strict warning: Only variables should be passed by reference in include() (line 18 of /home/sites/dev/theparce/sites/all/themes/parce/block--block--3.tpl.php).

This is the block code which is causing that error.

```
if ($user_gallery) {
  print render(node_show($user_gallery));  // Line 18
  print drupal_render ($user_gallery_edit);

}
else {
  print drupal_render($user_gallery_new);
}
```

Why do I get that error, even if I get all printed as expected?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

That error happens when a function is expecting a reference as parameter, but it is not getting a reference.

In your case, [`render()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/render/7) is defined as `render(&$element)`, but [`node_show()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.module/function/node_show/7) is defined as `node_show($node, $message = FALSE)`, not `&node_show($node, $message = FALSE)`.
The same would be true for [`drupal_render()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7), since the function is defined as `drupal_render(&$elements)`.

As explained on [Passing by Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php), when a function requires a reference parameter, you can pass to the function:

- Variables (for example, a temporary variable containing the result of a function which is not returning a reference)
- References returned from functions

Using other expressions, the result is undefined, and it depends from the PHP version.

- `render(node_show())` produces a fatal error in PHP 5.0.5, a strict standards notice in PHP 5.1.1, and a notice in PHP 7.0.0
- `render(5)` produces a fatal error
- `render(new DateTime())` produces a notice in PHP 7.0.7 (*Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference*)