# How do I render contextual links for blocks I render in my code?

Tags: 7, blocks

I loaded a block subject and content with `module_invoke()` and used `render()` for rendering them. I want to use contextual links for this block. How can I render them too?

This is the code I am using insde the page--front.tpl.php template.

```
$block = module_invoke('block', 'block_view', '4);
print render($block);
```

What code should I instead use?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$block = block_load('module', 'delta');
print drupal_render(_block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block))));
```

Too bad we have to use private functions from the block module (_*()) to achieve this.

Comment: So for the OPs example it would be: $block = block_load('block', '4');

Answer (score 12):

Bart's answer will give a Strict Standards warning (enabled by default in PHP 5.4). To fix this just use an intermediate variable for the renderable array:

```
$block = block_load('module', 'delta');
$renderable_array = _block_get_renderable_array(_block_render_blocks(array($block)));
print drupal_render($renderable_array);
```

The reason the warning occurs is because the `drupal_render` function expects its parameter to be a reference. It has the signature `drupal_render(&$elements)`. For more information see the answer to [this similar question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6322/strict-warning-only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference-in-include).

Answer (score 2):

Contextual links are helpful and really easy to implement.
For your use-case you need to implement `hook_block_view_alter()` to change #contextual_links item to suit your needs.
These references will help you out:

- http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/contextual
- http://dominiquedecooman.com/blog/drupal-7-tip-add-contextual-links-anything

GL :)

Comment: What OP means is that he programmatically displays the block, but contextual links aren't added.